# Confusion about fftshift and fft2 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm mighty confused about how to correctly apply the FFT transform and its inverse in Matlab. I have a program where I need to

1. apply FFT2 to a matrix of size 4x32 (corresponding to modes `m=-1:2`, `n=-15:16`)
2. do some processing, which leads to a coefficient matrix for another function, whose Fourier coefficients relate to the first set of data by a simple algebraic (component-wise) formula
3. Use some properties of the two functions that lets me calculate what I need by just summing up an expression on the form `2*abs(A_n)*cos(phi+n*theta+alpha_n)` where `A_n` is the nth coefficient of the `m=1` mode and `alpha_n = arg(A_n)`.

I have experimented a little with the FFT2 function and tried to understand how it arranges its output. From what I understand (from sources in my course literature), the coefficients will be ordered as is illustrated by the following script:

```
>>m = -1:2; n = -7:8;
>>[N,M] = meshgrid(n,m); 
>>MN = M; MN(:,:,2) = N; 
>>asfft = @(X) [X(2:4,8:16,:) X(2:4,1:7,:); X(1,8:16,:) X(1,1:7,:)];
>>asfft(MN)
ans(:,:,1) =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
ans(:,:,2) =
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1
```

where `asfft` reorders the indices in the same way I believe `fft2` does, but does nothing else. In other words, each index is ordered from 0 up to the max, then from the min to -1. According to the documentation, I should be able to rearrange this so I get 0 in the middle by using `fftshift`, but it's not giving me the output I expect. Instead, I get this:

```
>> fftshift(asfft(MN))
ans(:,:,1) =
     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
     8    -7    -6    -5    -4    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
ans(:,:,2) =
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

As you can see, the max is on the wrong side of the spectrum - instead of `-7 -6 ... -1 0 1 ... 8` and `-1 0 1 2` I have `8 -7 6 ...` and `2 -1 0 1`. This is fatal for me, since to be able to do the calculation described in 3 above, I need to know the indices of the respective coefficients. (The two layers are also switched, but that doesn't matter for me since I'm only going to do this on MxN matrices, not on N-d-arrays, later.)

Why is this? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the simple 1D case first, `fft` gives you:

```
[X(0) X(1) X(2) ... X(N/2-1) X(-N/2) X(-N/2+1) ... X(-1)]
```

where I'm using `X(k)` to denote elements of the [mathematical DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition).

All `fftshift` does is rotate these by `N/2`, so you end up with:

```
[X(-N/2) X(-N/2+1) ... X(-1) X(0) X(1) X(2) ... X(N/2-1)]
```

i.e. linear order.<sup>1</sup>

In the multi-dimensional case, `fftshift` simply applies this rotation in all dimensions.

---

<sub>1. Although since by definition, `X(k) == X(N+k)` for a DFT, the unrotated vector is also in "linear" order!</sub>

Comment: Sure - that's about the same information as what I get from the Matlab documentation. However, why do I get the ordering I showed in the post instead of what you show?

Comment: @TomasLycken: You do get the same order as what I've said, you've just numbered your data -7 -> +8, rather than the more conventional -8 -> +7.

Answer (score 0):

Check this newsread entry too
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285244

Comment: Link-only answers are generally considered low-quality on SO; if the linked page goes down, the answer is useless.

Answer (score -1):

taking a queue from Oli, the problem is that you're not parsing it in the middle:

so for `asfft = @(X) [X(2:4,8:16,:) X(2:4,1:7,:); X(1,8:16,:) X(1,1:7,:)];`

```
size(8:16)
ans =
     1     9
size(1:7)
ans =
     1     7
```

so do:

```
asfft = @(X) [X(3:4,9:16,:) X(3:4,1:8,:); X(1:2,9:16,:) X(1:2,1:8,:)];
```

Comment: Will this correspond to how FFT2 orders my coefficients?

Comment: as oli pointed out, you also need to do `m = -2:1; n = -8:7;` and you should be there

Comment: That's not an option, given the physical experiment that I am using data from. I've updated my post to clarify this.

Comment: @TomasLycken my comment reflects how to parse your code to be equivalent to fft2's (don't ask me to change the definition, cause I can't). My answer corresponds to the bug in *your code*, and my solution will put the `8` and `2` on the right side of the matrix.

Comment: I should mention you can't have it both ways: either you have `0 to max` and therefore an asymmetrical matrix, or `1 to max` and a symmetrical matrix which will give you the desired results. Square pegs don't fit in round holes